# Periodic orbits in planar smooth billiard table with large periods

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations, billiards

Given a plane billiard table with a smooth boundary which is a Jordan curve, I wonder if there is always a periodic orbit with sufficiently large period.

**Formulation of my question:** We are considering a [dynamical billiard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) $B$ sitting in an Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\partial B$ is a smooth Jordan curve (possibly non-convex). For any positive integer $N$, **is it true that there always exists an integer $n\ge N$ and an $n$-period trajectory?** Here period $n$ means the closed orbit has $n$ bouncing points (the particle returns to the beginning position and direction only after $n$ times of reflection).
Is there any $B$ such that all periodic orbits in $B$ have a uniform upper bound on their periods?

---

Some clues: For strictly *convex* $B$, a beautiful elementary argument due to Birkhoff asserts that there are $n$-periodic orbits for any $n\ge2$. See eg. [this page](https://www.dynamical-systems.org/billiard/info.html) or Theorem 6.2 of [Tabachnikov's book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-_31daRgHByJZ1xqlOuPU9TWp9Kr8gZ/view?usp=share_link). Also in [arXiv:1409.5201](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5201v1) Arnaud proves that for a generic differentiable billiard table the periodic points are dense; it seems quite natural to believe the smooth members all have many periodic orbits.

A technical obstruction of generalizing the Birkhoff argument to non-convex smooth cases is that one cannot ensure that the critical point of the length function gives a legal trajectory that sits inside the interior of non-convex billiard table. But intuitively I guess this subtlety may be remedied by allowing the period (bouncing times) $n$ to be sufficiently large, hence the question.

Comment: Can we assume you intended that *M* = *N* ?

Comment: @DanielAsimov Yes, that's a typo. my mistake. Just edited